# How can I configure EMR to read from an S3 bucket by a User Access Id and Secret Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

Is there a way to read from an S3 bucket which is not in your AWS account and you cannot assume a role to gain access to it - specifically in EMR.

In plain Hadoop or Spark you can specify:

```
fs.s3.access.key=<accessKey>
fs.s3.secret.ket=<secretKey>
```

in the Hadoop configuration using SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.
This is working locally, however when attempting to run on EMR which makes use of EMRS I am unable to get this to work, I always get a 403:

```
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403
```

I only have an IAM User Access Id and Secret Key to read from the bucket, my instance profile which creates the EMR EC2 instances does not have permissions to read the bucket.

To give more context, I read and write from multiple s3 buckets within the account the EMR is provisioned but there is this one bucket which lives outside I am trying to access.

EDIT

This is for a Scala Spark application where I'm attempting to load contents of an S3 bucket directly into a Dataframe.

Comment: You can define in the bucket policy permissions for IAM roles that are in different accounts. The IAM role doesn't have to be in the same account as the bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
just so I understand correctly, that would mean updating the bucket policy on the bucket I am attempting to read from, to include the role I assume (in the account I'm provisioning EMR) i.e EMR_EC2_DefaultRole

Answer (score 0):

can you try using "boto3" library in pyspark to see if you can read the file.

**something like this:**

s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key_id=SECRET_KEY))

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
...     print(bucket.name)

Link to sample: https://www.datastackpros.com/2020/05/upload-file-to-s3-bucket-using-python.html

More boto3 functions: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/collections.html

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this is for a Scala Spark application.
I want to load contents from an S3 bucket directly into a Spark Dataframe

Answer (score 0):

you are sadly trying to use the configuration options for the Apache S3A connector, but running on Amazon EMR, which has its own connector and its own configuration keys.

See what the options are there and set them in your job alongside the s3a options

Comment: I believe I also tried fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey but to now avail. But I believe they should be the correct ones so will look into some more.